# Query DNS in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, dns, ubuntu-10.04

I use two DNS servers a public one (8.8.8.8)
and a local one (192.168.1.20)
In ubuntu, If I wrote both DNSs 192.168.1.20, 8.8.8.8
it will always query the first and until the first is down and then it will start querying the second.
And of course I have to make the local point again to 8.8.8.8 
Like this i have almost no problems, I can resolve local addresses and also public ones
but when I'm out of the office that's were all the problems start.
Having the local DNS first makes ubuntu checks for it every single time it needs to resolve.
So I end up switching switching the priority of the DNS every (8.8.8.8, 192.168.1.20) time I change my location.

This is not the case if I was using windows. It somehow sends to both DNSs at once or something of that sort.
Is there a way to avoid changing the DNS for every location?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu also must query each server in /etc/resolv.conf if there is no answer from the first server.
Give an output of 'dig google.com' please

---

You wrote 'until the first is down'...
The system of course will connect other servers ONLY if has no respond from the first one!!
The servers are listed in preferable order

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But it will do that in every domain request
and you wait about 4 sec for every time it has to check the first server. And it does that not just once and moves on . it keep doing it every time a domain is requested. 
so when you open yahoo for example, you wait 4sec X number of subdomains & domains.
which is unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a possible work around.
Are you able to use different network interfaces for each network?
If so you can specify different "dns-nameservers" in the "/etc/network/interfaces" file.